# How to fetch data in Angular

Tags: angular, http, httpresponse, angular-http, angular-httpclient

can someone help me with getting number from http response in Angular 5 ? I don't now how to do it, I was searching at internet but Angular grow very fast so it doesn't help me. Thanks for any help !

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../entities/User';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private usersurl: 'http://localhost:8080/api/users';

  user: User;
  id: number;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.user != null;
  }

  isAdmin() {
    return this.user.isAdmin;
  }

  unLoggin() {
    this.user = null;
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.id = null;
    this.http.get<number>(`${this.usersurl}/verify?username=${username}&password=${password}`).subscribe(id => this.id = id);
    alert(this.id);
    if (this.id != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

It alert [object Object]
localhost:8080/api/users/verify returns for example 8 only 8 no json formated 8

Comment: What do you mean getting "number?"

Comment: Do you want data in number format rather than string?  Can you put some code as well as json format?

Comment: @KHAN - API server return plain number exa. 2

Comment: @ErikBystroň Still not making sense, please add more detail to your question and what code you have tried so far.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr I tried this.http.get<number>(this.usersurl + '/verify?username=' + username + '&password=' + password).subscribe(val => this.id = val); but it return [object Object]

Comment: @Erik Bystroň, as you can see some possible answer below, likewise , put codes of .ts, html, service.ts etc for better understanding of your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a Http call inside of Angular we can use the `HttpClient`. This requires us to import the `HttpClientModule` inside of our root module (app.module.ts):

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

// Omitted other dependencies for brevity
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [DataService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Inside of our service (i.e. data.service.ts) which we've registered as a provider, we can inject HttpClient and use the `get` method:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  ROOT_URL = 'http://your-api.com';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUserId(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<number>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/verify?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
  }
}
```

Inside of our Component we can then subscribe to the Observable emitted from our service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>UserId: {{userId}}</h1>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  userId: number;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService
      .getUserId('test', 'password')
      .subscribe(id => this.userId = id);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, we can use the Async pipe to let Angular handle the subscription:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>UserId: {{userId$ | async}}</h1>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  userId$: Observable<Number>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId$ = this.dataService.getUserId('test', 'password');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't works, id is still undefined... https://hastebin.com/micoworuke.js

Answer (score 0):

When you make a HTTP request it returns a observable object which you subscribe to. If you want to manipulate the data and only return the id you can use the map function.

```
function getUserID() {

    return this.http.get('this.usersurl + '/verify?username=' + username + 
    '&password=' + password').map(val => val.id)
}

this.getUserID.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data); // should return the id (number).
});
```

So the above returns only the id (number) of the val object.

Comment: it can only be used on constructor

Comment: @ErikBystroň This is not helpful, you make no attempt at trying it and providing proper feedback.

Comment: I added my actual code upper and some more info. The cause of this will be plain number not number in json  format....